# Unable to Implement a Model in Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision

I have been trying to implement this paper (https://doi.org/10.1109/ICASSP40776.2020.9054563). Now, for the last many days, I am stuck with an error in the model.
The model that I want to mimic is as follows:

[Paper Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiJOf.png)

Where deconvolution has been performed using subpixel layers.
The code for the model is as follows:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, upscale_factor = 2):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
#         self.input_start = nn.(16,256,3)
        self.e1 = nn.Conv2d(16,16, (5,1),stride = (1,2),padding='valid')
        self.e1_dr = nn.Dropout(.5)
        
        self.e2 = nn.Conv2d(128,128, (5,1),stride = (1,2),padding='valid')
#         self.e2.weight
        self.e2_dr = nn.Dropout(.5)

        self.e3 = nn.Conv2d(256, 256,(5,1),stride = (1,2),padding='valid')
        self.e3_dr = nn.Dropout(.5)

        self.e4 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, (5,1),stride = (1,2),padding='valid')
        
        self.e5 = nn.Conv2d(512,512, (5,1),stride = (2,2),padding='valid')
        
        self.e6 = nn.Conv2d(512,512, (3,1),stride = (2,2),padding='valid')
        
        self.e7 = nn.Conv2d(512,512, (3,1),stride = (2,2),padding='valid')
        
        self.e8 = nn.Conv2d(512,512, (3,1),stride = (2,2),padding='valid')
        
        self.d1 = nn.PixelShuffle(upscale_factor )
        self.d2 = nn.PixelShuffle(upscale_factor)
        self.d3 = nn.PixelShuffle(upscale_factor)
        self.d4 = nn.PixelShuffle(upscale_factor)
        self.d5 = nn.PixelShuffle(upscale_factor )
        self.d6 = nn.PixelShuffle(upscale_factor)
        self.d7 = nn.PixelShuffle(upscale_factor)
        self.d8 = nn.PixelShuffle(upscale_factor)

        

    def forward(self, x):
#         x = (F.leaky_relu(self.input_start(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.e1(x)))

        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.e1(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.e1_dr(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.e2(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.e2_dr(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.e3(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.e3_dr(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.e4(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.e5(x)))
        
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.e6(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.e7(x)))
        x = (self.e8(x))
        
        
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.d1(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.d2(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.d3(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.d4(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.d5(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.d6(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.d7(x)))
        x = (F.leaky_relu(self.d8(x)))


          
        return x
```

Whenever I run the model, I get the following error:
Given groups=1, weight of size [128, 128, 5, 1], expected input[2, 16, 248, 1] to have 128 channels, but got 16 channels instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch in the channel counts. Take a look at your model: the first convolution `e1` expects `16` channels and outputs `16` while the following convolution `e2` expects `128`! The `out_channels` of `e1` and the `in_channels` of `e2` must be equal.